# Spanish-English downloadable dictionary

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, spanish

I'm looking for a Spanish - English downloadable dictionary, similar to [CC-CEDICT](https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/) for Chinese.

> CC-CEDICT is a continuation of the CEDICT project. The objective of
>   the CEDICT project was to create an online, downloadable (as opposed
>   to searchable-only) public-domain Chinese-English dictionary.

The Chinese dictionary gives me a comprehensive text file of Character, Pronunciation (pinyin), Meaning:

```
㮚 㮚 [li4] /old variant of 栗[li4]/
㮸 㮸 [song4] /variant of 送[song4]/
㯭 橹 [lu3] /variant of 櫓|橹[lu3]/
```

Is there any such downloadable dictionary for Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a few that may be useful, depending on what you want to do:

- [Manuel Bueno's Spanish-English-Spanish XML dictionary](https://github.com/mananoreboton/en-es-en-Dic) consists of a Spanish-English and an English-Spanish XML file. The licence is Apache 2.0, which is very liberal.
- [Elliot Cooper's Spanish_Dictionary](https://github.com/groodle/Spanish_Dictionary) for Kindle has source files that may be useful. The project is available under the GPL 2 licence, so you can only reuse it in projects with a GPL-compatible licence.
- [shakespeare](https://github.com/xr09/shakespeare) is a Spanish-English dictionary. You can find the database under `src/core/dict.db`. According to the person who put it on GitHub, the dictionary is "old" (whatever that means). Unfortunately, the repository has no licence, so it is unclear whether you can reuse it (except privately).
- [Gaurav's SpanishEnglishDictionary](https://github.com/ggaurav/SpanishEnglishDictionary) for Nokia S40 phones. The `config.xml`, however, describes it as an English-Spanish dictionary. Unfortunately, this is another repository without a proper licence file.

Comment: Thanks for these. I'm looking for an API/Downloadable Dictionary that is conjugation-sensitive. Meaning, if I search `quiero`, I get back "yo (I) form of querer". Do these exist?

Comment: I think that goes beyond the capabilities of the resources I listed. A stemmer, such as the one in [Python NLTK](http://text-processing.com/demo/stem/) would just give you the stem, not the infinitive, of "quiero". On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8418302/6002174), someone suggested using [Hunspell](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Hunspell) as an alternative to the Porter stemmer. I don't know if that will do the trick...

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded a es-en dictionary a while back that includes only genders per word and the English definitions. So what I was planning on doing is modifying each row I need to include conjugations: `querer; desear - want - <yo: quiero>, <tú: quieres>... etc`. This takes a lot of time to do per word I need for my app. Would stemming in Spanish/using hunspell give me the conjugations I need?

Comment: I think it's worth looking for either an existing database/list of conjugations (e.g. [fred-jehle-spanish-verbs
](https://github.com/ghidinelli/fred-jehle-spanish-verbs)) or a library that can generate conjugated forms (e.g. [conjugator](https://github.com/ehoogerbeets/conjugator) or [Spanish-Verb-Conjugation-Creator](https://github.com/lkuza2/Spanish-Verb-Conjugation-Creator)). I would carefully look whether an appropriate licence is available, especially if you want to release your code.