# Any downloadable dictionaries of commonly used words?

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, electronic-resources, spanish

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but here it goes.

I need a dictionary file (XML, JSON, or any other computer readable format) that contains the most commonly used words in one language and their meaning in another. For example a Spanish to English dictionary would have the Spanish word "la mesa" and its corresponding English translation "the table". I need these for the most commonly used languages, but a Spanish-English pair would be a good start).

Does anyone know where I could find such files?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! Your question is on-topic here, but in order to receive higher quality answers, you should specify exactly what language(s) you want this dictionary for.

Comment: There are many dictionaries and lists available on the web. However, there are around 7,000 languages, so please specify which language combination (e.g. Spanish to English) you need.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2918/800) answer your question? If not, please describe more precisely what you are looking for.